# Identify gaps in a sequence in one cell - Excel

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of items in my Excel sheet that are numbered, together with a total number, in the following way:

*Example:*

```
   | Column A (available) | Column B (missing) | Column C (total)
___|______________________|____________________|_________________
1  | 01 - 13              |         ?          | 20
2  | 02 - 09              |         ?          | 10
3  | 01 - 04, 06 - 11     |         ?          | 11
```

Now, I want Column B to display the missing item numbers, like this:

```
   | Column A (available) | Column B (missing) | Column C (total)
___|______________________|____________________|_________________
1  | 01 - 13              | 14 - 20            | 20
2  | 02 - 09              | 01, 10             | 10
3  | 01 - 04, 06 - 11     | 05                 | 11
```

I have managed to create a long-winded formula for cases like in line 1, but that only works by checking the last two digits of a cell in Column A, subtracting it from Column C's value in that line, then fill in Column B with the result.

(basically something like this (with some special cases not affected by the "gap problem" at hand)): `$C1-Right($A1;2)&" - "&$C1`)

But my approach (obviously) can't handle the gaps like in lines 2 and 3, and I want to know if there is a way to solve my issue.

P.S. I wasn't sure what title to give to this problem, so I apologize if it is misleading.

Comment: A formula cannot do that - you will need a VBA macro. Good luck.

Comment: I'd think a function that includes a For-Next loop that check to see if the cycle number of the loop is included in any of the values in column A would be a start. You'd, of course, set the top value of the loop to the corresponding value in column C.

Comment: Is Col A always in exactly that format (single digits w/leading zeros, space-hyphen-space between numbers to specify a range, comma-space between ranges)? Can Col A formatting be adjusted so more conducive to parsing?  Do the ranges always start at 1?  Can the total (Col C) be anything, or is there an upper limit that no range will exceed?  Is there a maximum potential number of ranges in Col A?  Can Col A also contain single numbers?  Does Col B need to be a comma-delimited list of numbers plus ranges, or would it work as just a list of individual numbers, even if some are sequential numbers?

Comment: The Output patterns are not similar so I don't think any single Formula will works for all Rows,, better edit the Question and do necessary corrections otherwise it may attract to Vote it to Close !!

Answer (score -1):

**Your problem can be solved by using the TREND function:**

[image]

1. Taking the first data sample in Column A, you need to create **1st sequence from 1 to 13** and **2nd from 1 to 20**.
2. Write this Array Formula in Cell `C1`, finish with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` & fill down.

`{=TREND(A1:A13,B1:B13,B14:B20)}`

1. You get series from `14 to 20`.
2. In `D1` enter this Formula to get the `1st Cell value`.
               `=INDEX(C1:C7,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((C1:C7<>0),0),0))`
3. Enter this Formula in `D2` to get `last Cell value`.

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(C1:C7<>""),C1:C7)`

4. In Cell `D4` enter this one `=D1&"-"&D2`, you get `14-20`.

**Note:**
For 2nd data sample you need to create 2 series.

1- `2 to 9`.

2- `1 to 10`.

3rd data sample needs 3 series.

1- `1 to 4`.

2- `6 to 11`.

3- `1 to 11`.

1. Repeat the above shown steps for other data samples.
2. Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.

Comment: This is an outside the box solution Some clever stuff here, but it needs a custom solution for each row. There's also the undocumented steps of recreating the data in a usable format. By the time you're done figuring out what setup is needed and creating it, it might be less work to just do it manually. It seems like to be a valid answer, it needs to start with the given data in the given form, end with the specified result, and accomplish all of the required steps in between. What's here only really deals with part of the problem, and isn't an automated, general solution. But a good start.

Comment: Thanks @fixer1234 for valuable observation. This is what I found is working with the given data. Hope OP & others will like it ☺

Comment: Just write your concern why Down voted,,?